# Control when ARI function is called using JQuery/socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, socket.io, asterisk

So I currently have two functions which are called when I add a call to a bridge, and two functions within that get called automatically, so am trying to use JQuery so they only get called when a button is clicked, and then I can work from there in the server side of things.

It may have be an issue with using both ARI client and socket.io together, am not too sure am still learning as am going along.

Issue being at the moment an error gets thrown up saying $ isnt defined.

JQuery does work I have another file am calling which is all JQuery and handles my socket.io client side.

```
    $("#mute").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.mute({
            channelId : 111
        },
            function (err) {});
    });

    $("#kick").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.hangup({
            channelId : 111
        },

function (err) {});
    });
```

As anyone any experience using both or even have any suggestion as to how I can do this.

Full code listing;

```
var ari = require('ari-client');
var util = require('util');
var chanArr = [];
var test;
var mute;
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//ARI client
ari.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'asterisk', 'asterisk', clientLoaded);

function clientLoaded(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // find or create a holding bridges
    var bridge = null;
    client.bridges.list(function (err, bridges) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        bridge = bridges.filter(function (candidate) {
                return candidate.bridge_type === 'mixing';
            })[0];

        if (bridge) {
            console.log(util.format('Using bridge %s', bridge.id));
        } else {
            client.bridges.create({
                type : 'mixing'
            }, function (err, newBridge) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                bridge = newBridge;
                console.log(util.format('Created bridge %s', bridge.id));
            });
        }
    });

    // handler for StasisStart event
    function stasisStart(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just entered our application, adding it to bridge %s',
                channel.name,
                bridge.id));

        channel.answer(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            bridge.addChannel({
                channel : channel.id
            }, function (err) {
                var id = chanArr.push(channel.name)
                    console.log("Value: " + test);
                test = channel.name;
                updateSip);

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                //If else statement to start music for first user entering channel, music will stop once more than 1 enters the channel.
                if (chanArr.length <= 1) {
                    bridge.startMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                } else if (chanArr.length === 2) {
                    bridge.stopMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                } else {}

            });

        });
        $("#mute").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.mute({
            channelId : 111
        },
            function (err) {});
    });

    $("#kick").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.hangup({
            channelId : 111
        },
    }

    // handler for StasisEnd event
    function stasisEnd(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just left our application', channel.name));
        console.log(channel.name);

        var index = chanArr.indexOf(channel.name);
        chanArr.splice(index, 1);
        updateSip();
    }
    client.on('StasisStart', stasisStart);
    client.on('StasisEnd', stasisEnd);
    client.start('bridge-hold');
}

//Socket.io logic here
server.listen(3009, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3009');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/testPage.html");
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (data) {
    updateSip();
});

io.sockets.on('muting', function (data) {
    mute = data;
    console.log("client side:" + mute);
});

function updateSip() {
    console.log("Value: " + test);
    io.sockets.emit('sip', chanArr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error saying $ isnt defined would be jQuery not being available. If we could see more of the code as its structured on the page, why it is not available would be more clear.

Comment: Which is correct but I believe the issue is at the moment is that this ARI segment is loaded before the JQuery lib. Ill update the full code listing for clarity. I am using a work around at the moment of simply passing a value to the server side code from the client side and storing it in a glibal far, then doing an if else for my ARI logic at the moment.